# PDO returns false on fetch when the table has the name with underscore

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have this simple function that returns an user_id base on employee code received by parameter, the problem is, the fetch returns false, I tried with another table name and works fine. Does PDO has some limitations with tables that has _ in the name ?
The table is fos_user, created with symfony using the FOS User bundle.

Here is the code.

```
private function getUserId(string $num_empleado): int {

    $stmt = $this->handler->prepare("SELECT id FROM fos_user WHERE numempleado = :numempleado");

    $stmt->execute([":numempleado" => $num_empleado]);

    $user_id = $stmt->fetch();
    var_dump($user_id); die;

    return $stmt->fetch()["id"];
}
```

I also tried to store the name of the table in a variable and concatenate, but with the same results.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything about an underscore being restricted.

Try quoting the table name though, its always a good idea anyway.  Use **back ticks**, not actual quotes.

```
`fos_user`
```

Comment: thanks you for the reply, but i forgot to say that i also tried with backticks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no restriction on underscore characters in an identifier.

Identifiers can be case sensitive (depending on the MySQL server configuration).

An identifier needs to be escaped if it includes spaces, dots, or other characters that are disallowed.

But if the issue was with an invalid or unknown identifier, we'd expect the `prepare` or `execute` to throw an error.

If the `fetch` is being called, then that means we have a valid handle to a statement.  If an error had occurred, then `$stmt` would be FALSE, not a statement handle, and we'd be seeing a PHP error (a boolean does not have a fetch method/function.)

A fetch will return FALSE when there are no more rows to return.

The behavior described in the question seems to indicate that the query is executing successfully, but the query is returning an empty resultset.

In terms of SQL, it's valid for a SELECT to return zero rows.

We're going to assume that these two lines of code

```
    $user_id = $stmt->fetch();
    var_dump($user_id); die;
```

were added for debugging.

If we're expecting one row to be returned, it doesn't make sense to issue another fetch...

```
    $stmt->fetch()
```